# Octave, sometimes plots are just black with a white box in top left corner, sometimes they work

Tags: octave

I have had this problem for a while where sometimes my plots in octave appear like this [image: this] instead of how they are supposed to be. This seems completely random and sometimes it just works fine. I'm running linux mint 19 and I am using the command line version of octave e.g. started with

octave --no-gui

and then I launch scripts from there.

Comment: I can verify that I have experienced the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04, with octave started in gui mode (in Virtual Box though). But I mean, is this really a programming question/error? Seems to be a bug in Octave.

Comment: Try adding this command `set(gca, 'color', 'none');` as the last  statement. This will suppress painting any color to the background of the plot.